# Find every string before every matched string

Tags: regex, bash, notepad++

I am racking my brain trying to figure out how to make a regex to find what I am looking for. I would like to find every occurrence of an item, and then the first string from a previous line that goes with that item. Below is an example

```
.
<tag name="host-ip">192.168.5.4</tag>
.
[Poodle 12345]
.
<tag name="host-ip">192.168.5.75</tag>
.
[Poodle 12345]
```

Each dot represents multiple lines of text which isn’t relevant. I also need to search on the Poodle string, not IPs. The IP is listed first in the xml file, and then the host is vulnerable to Poodle, [Poodle 12345] is displayed in the report. I would like a list of just the IPs found, but the Poodle string needs to be found first and then the previous random IP that goes with that vuln needs to be displayed. (As displayed below)

```
192.168.5.4
192.168.5.75
.
.
192.168.5.100
```

It would be easiest to do this in Notepad++ using regex since it’s an xml file, but outputting via cmd line would work as well. Any help would be appreciated as I am not a reg-ex expert. Even if this isn’t possible, anything that would put me on the right track would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Given the sample text you've shown, I would write

```
awk -F'[<>]' '/tag name="host-ip"/ {ip=$3} /Poodle 12345/ {print ip}' file
```

Another approach that came to mind would be to reverse the file. Then when you find "Poodle", output the *next* IP seen.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would use lookahead assertion: looking for an IP address which are followed by some strings and then this `[Poodle 12345]` string.
Here is regex:

```
(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?=<\/tag>[\na-z\."]*\n\[Poodle\s[\d]{5}\])
```

Some explanations:

- `(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}` ip address;
- `(?=` lookahead assertion;
- `<\/tag>[\na-z\."]*\n\[Poodle\s[\d]{5}\]` what we are expecting to be after an IP address.

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/gT0zO3/2